# Python sha256 hash padding issue

Tags: python, sha256

I have a issue with the padding of a sha256 hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import hashlib
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

code = str(sys.argv[1])
print(code)

array = [["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""]]
counter = 0
iteration = 1

file = open("hashes.txt", "r")
for i in file:
  if iteration == 1:
    array[counter][0] = str(i)
    iteration = 2
  else:
    array[counter][1] = str(i)
    iteration = 1

  if iteration == 1:
  counter = counter +1;

print(array)

print([array[0][0]])
print pbkdf2_sha256.verify(code,array[0][0])
```

The script in the link above gets invoked by a .php file, passing the parameter 'code'. Then a list of hashes with corresponding usernames gets read out of a text file and stored into a list.

The output of the script with the text file containing only one hash and name looks like this:

2244 [['$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$AuCcU0pJidHam1NKyXnPmQ$TmzQ.cWXKnx7u.dd023qoltVxeuaPafEq7Lvyywxf9o\n', 'Fabian'], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']] ['$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$AuCcU0pJidHam1NKyXnPmQ$TmzQ.cWXKnx7u.dd023qoltVxeuaPafEq7Lvyywxf9o\n']

As you can see this works perfectly, but a '\n' gets appended to the hash both times it gets printed. I suppose that is the reason why the very last print throws a 'TypeError: Incorrect padding'.

The problem is: I don't know how to make this work since both name and hash would get written in the same line if I remove the '\n'. I tried to write the lines in the text file both manually and with a script using

```
file = open("hashes.txt","w")
file.write(hash)
file.write("Fabian")
```

but this doesn't solve the problem. Note: the text file looks like this:

```
hash0
name0
hash1
name1
etc
```

Has anyone of you been in this situation? Any help or idea is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `\n` is the new line special character. If you want the information in separate lines, you need it. If you don't want it, the the data won't be in different lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the newline escape character after having read a line using [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

```
line = "123\n"
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Hey, this solved my problem. I tried to strip it in a different way previously without success. Thank you.